Newton-Kantorovich: theorem geometric
This post is cross-posted from Math StackExchange where I did not receive any response after 5 days. I guess this question might be targeted more towards research level mathematics, so I decided that it might be suitable here. There are several visual illustrations and details in that post, this is the concise version.
I am trying to find geometric intuition for the Newton-Kantorovich theorem, specifically for real numbers. The theorem states:

Newton-Kantorovich Theorem
Given a differentiable function $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open interval, let $x_0$ be a point in $\Omega$ such that its derivative at that point is invertible ($f'(x_0)^{-1}$ is defined). Define
$$
> h_0=-f(x_0)^{-1}f(x_0), \quad x_1=x_0+h_0
> $$
If the open ball $B(x_1, \|h_0\|)$ is contained inside $\Omega$, and $L$ is the Lipschitz constant of the derivative $f'(x)$ over the ball, then if
$$
> \|f(x_0)\|\|f'(x_0)^{-1}\|^2L \leq \frac{1}{2}
> $$
is satisfied, then:

$f(x)=0$ has a unique solution in the closed ball $\bar{B}(x_1,\|h_0|)$.
The Newton iteration starting from $x_0$ converges to this solution at least linearly.


Geometric Intuition
For $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:

Newton Step Interpretation:

The Newton step can be visualized as drawing a tangent from $(x, f(x))$ to the x-intercept, forming a right-angled triangle.
Magnitude of the Newton step:
$$
|\Delta x| = \frac{|f(x)|}{|f'(x)|}
$$


Applying to $f'(x)$:

A Newton step on $f'(x)$:
$$
|\Delta x| = \frac{|f'(x)|}{|f''(x)|}
$$
The area of the corresponding triangle:
$$
\text{Area} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{|f'(x)|^2}{|f''(x)|}
$$
This resembles the inequality in the theorem but uses $f''(x)$ instead of the Lipschitz constant $L$.



Example
Consider $f(x) = \frac{x^4}{4} - \frac{x^2}{2}$ on $]0,2[$:

Root: $x = \sqrt{2} \approx 1.414$
Starting point $x_0 = 1.5$:
$$
f(1.5) = 0.140625, \quad f'(1.5) = 1.875, \quad f''(1.5) = 5.75
$$
Newton step:
$$
\|h_0\| = \frac{0.140625}{1.875} = 0.075, \quad x_1 = 1.5 - 0.075 = 1.425
$$
Open ball $B(1.425, 0.075) = ]1.35, 1.5[$
Lipschitz constant $L = 5.75$
Triangle area:
$$
\text{Area} \approx \frac{1}{2} \frac{1.875^2}{5.75} \approx 0.305706522
$$
Inequality check:
$$
f(x_0) \leq \text{Area}, \quad 0.140625 \leq 0.305706522
$$

Questions

Are there more natural geometric interpretations of this theorem for real numbers? Comparing units of length to area is awkward, and I am specifically thinking about units with the same dimensions.
Is there a natural or interesting extension of this interpretation to higher dimensions? Earlier, I've shown algebraically that based on the properties of the operator norm, $$\|f(x_0\| \leq \frac{1}{2}\frac{\|f'(x_0)^{-1}\|^{-2}}{L} \leq \frac{1}{2}\frac{\|f'(x_0)\|^2}{L}$$since $f'(x_0)$ is bounded and linear so $$\|x\|=\|f'(x_0)^{-1}f'(x_0)(x)\| \leq \|f'(x_0)^{-1}\|\|f'(x_0)\|\|x\|$$$$\|f'(x_0)^{-1}\|^{-1} \leq \|f'(x_0)\|$$ but I am not sure what to make of this.
Could such a geometric perspective be used for a proof or heuristic argument for convergence? It would be interesting if this can provide better intuition about the theorem.

Thanks in advance for your insights.

Have you tried reading the exposition in Hubbard's Calculus textbook?  It's pretty helpful.

Is it this?
https://download.tuxfamily.org/openmathdep/calculus_advanced/Vector_Calculus-Hubbards.pdf

Yes, that's it.

Oh wait it's the same as this, I've seen this but there isn't really geometric intuition
https://matrixeditions.com/VC.Chap2.243-244.pdf

That's the statement of the theorem, not the proof.
